# Adding https binding from ASP.NET MVC application hosted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8, iis-10

I have an Application hosted in IIS website **TestWebsite** and i am using Microsoft.Web.Administration for IIS Automation.

I have to do following operations with bindings of the SAME website **TestWebsite** from **TestWebsite**

1. Add HTTPS binding with SSL certificate to the website "TestWebsite" from same application (code to add binding will be in same "TestWebsite")
2. Remove the Binding.

I have done the following code and weird thing is that on localhost it is adding the https binding but even before **manager.commitchange()**. This line throw exception on local host, so i removed this line but on Windows Server its not adding the binding even after successfully running the code. (without commitchanges(),  i hv no idea how its working on localhost without it)

**I am using IIS 10 on localhost and IIS 8.5 on staging and IIS 8.0 On Production.**

```
using (ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager())
{
    var website = iisManager.Sites.Where(x => x.Name == "TestWebsite").FirstOrDefault();
    if (website != null)
    {
        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        var pfxPath = Server.MapPath(model.PfxPath);
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(pfxPath, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
        store.Add(certificate);
        store.Close();
        var certHash = certificate.GetCertHash();

        string bindingInformation = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", "*", "443", model.UserCustom);
        var binding = website.Bindings.Add(bindingInformation, certHash, store.Name);
        binding.Protocol = "https";
        store.Close();

        website.ApplicationDefaults.EnabledProtocols = "http,https";
        iisManager.CommitChanges();
    }
}
```

I receive following error on **iisManager.CommitChanges()** line

*A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070520)*

Is there some permission related error? What i am doing wrong in it?

Your help will be appreciated

Thank you  :)
Danial Malik

Comment: Where you ever able to solve this? I'm receiving the same error when trying to commit changes for a https binding.

Answer (score 0):

IIS would return 0x80070520 error when Adminsitrators group don't have permission to access 
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys. Please try to grant full control permission for your administrators group.

https://www.cnblogs.com/ziye/p/9208353.html

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2010/08/12/got-error-0x80070520-when-binding-certificate-to-web-site-on-iis-7/

Comment: What does "For your administrators group" mean? I went into properties of that MachineKeys folder and in security gave full permissions to Everyone and Administrator too, but it still has issues.
Microsoft.Web.Administration version 7 will work on IIS 8 and above?

Comment: I full permissions for administrator, administrators and everyone but its still throwing same error.

Comment: @DanyalMalik could you find any error message in event viewer？ Besides,could you try to enable process monitor and monitor whether any access denied error would be logged in the counter when you are trying to reproduce this issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon